# What's the point of the `select` effect in redux-saga?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

As redux-saga describes itself as

> a library that aims to make application `side effects` (i.e.
>   asynchronous things like data fetching and impure things like
>   accessing the browser cache) easier to manage.

The `select` effect is just used to `get a slice of the current Store's state`. It doesn't produce any side effect at all (no I/O operation, no mutation,etc). It's just a purely functional operation. Why a purely functional operation was designed to be an effect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because none of your saga code is supposed to be interacting with the store directly overall.  Whatever your saga needs to do, whether it be making an AJAX call, dispatching an action, or anything else, gets done by yielding an effect description and asking the middleware to do that work for you.  Your saga doesn't have access to the store directly to call `dispatch()`, so there's no reason for it to have access to `getState()` directly either.

Comment: What is the bad consequence if I call `store.getState()` directly? It's just a read-only operation. I don't think there is any bad to call store.getState() directly.

Comment: There may or may not be a problem. The issue isn't calling `store.getState()`, it's how you'd get access to the store itself.  Normally, your store setup file starts the root saga, which imports your other saga files.  By importing the store into a saga file, you're creating a circular dependency, and that could cause problems in the app.  Also see https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#store-setup-multiple-stores .  Besides, there's no good reason to call `store.getState()` in a saga. You've got the `select()` effect, it works - just use it.

Comment: "By importing the store into a saga file, you're creating a circular dependency, and that could cause problems in the app." That makes sense. Thanks!